# operation mode of an encryption algorithm

Tags: aes

> The operating mode of an encryption algorithm, especially a block
>   cipher, describes how to use the encryption function for a single
>   block repeatedly to encrypt or decrypt an entire messages with a
>   single key.

I've hard to understand what the operation mode of an encryption algorithm is. Is it an extension of the encryption algorithm like `AES` or is it a function that is applied along with the encryption algorithm to each single block of data?  If i'm wrong could someone provide a simple english definition on what it actually is ?

Comment: Did you read [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) from Wikipedia?

Comment: Don't know how but indeed I've missed it. Thank you! So basically it is an algorithm that is applied to the encryption algorithm?

Comment: Yes, technically they define encryption schemes. Look for encryption schemes vs encryption algorithm.

Comment: But the idea behind operation modes is that block ciphers are deterministic algorithms (given a particular input, will always produce the same output)   so applying them we avoid creating identical output ciphertext blocks from identical plaintext data, correct?

Comment: The IV [changes all](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66858/18298). For example, the CBC mode of operation is a [randomized encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption) that requires unpredictable IV.